# SSRS Report Builder: How to reference an image control in code?

Tags: reporting-services, report, builder

I'm using SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 to create paginated reports and I'm trying to display a line of text with each letter being an image control and displaying a letter as an embedded image.

The embedded images have their letter value as name A.png, B.png, ...

Currently each image control has code to define which image to display based on position of letter in the line of text:

1st letter: `=Mid(UCase(Parameters!MyLineOfText.Value),` **1**`, 1)`

2nd letter: `=Mid(UCase(Parameters!MyLineOfText.Value),` **2**`, 1)`

7th letter: `=Mid(UCase(Parameters!MyLineOfText.Value),` **7**`, 1)`, and so on

The thing is that I have multiple lines of text with 50 characters each and I would like to reference the letter index by the name of the image control.

Say my image control name is **Image01** then my code for the image control would be something like:
`=Mid(UCase(Parameters!MyLineOfText.Value), CInt(Right(` **Me.Name**`,2)), 1)`

Is such a reference possible? Or is there a different way to achieve this?

Example of letter image:
[image: Letter A], [image: Letter B]

The line of text can be anything but tipically in my case will be a customer name and a date of installation (as example).

Once the line is complete, should look like a split-flap board (more or less).

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Example data and an image of what you should see may help us understand this a bit more

Comment: Just edited the text with example images... Hope this helps